# Comparing two tables for changes into new table with three columns: identifying_column, new_data, changed_data

Tags: sql, comparison, compare, tableau-api

In a SQL DB I have two tables that I want to compare to find and display the changes in Tableau.

**Original_data**

```
Column names:
ID, 
Category, 
Company, 
Description, 
Update frequency #, 
Time since last update [hours], 
Measurement (hours/min)
```

**Original_Sample_data**:

```
ACC-1-Nike, ACC, Nike, shoes with acc, 12, 3, hours
```

**New_data**
Column names:

```
ID, 
Category, 
Company, 
Description, 
Update frequency #, 
Time since last update [hours],
Measurement (hours/min)
```

**New_Sample_data**:

```
ACC-1-Nike, ACC, Nike, shoes made of wood, 12, 3, hours
```

I have been trying to create a new table with three columns:

```
Column 1: Name of all the columns (to be compared)
Column 2: Original_Data_value
Column 3: New_Data_Value
```

**OUTPUT THAT I Want to achieve**:

```
----------------------------------------------------
| Column Names    |   Org_Value     | New_Value    |
----------------------------------------------------
|   ID            | ACC-1-NIKE      | ACC-1-NIKE   |
----------------------------------------------------
|   Category      | ACC             | ACC          |
----------------------------------------------------
|   Description   | shoes with acc  | shoes made of wood|
----------------------------------------------------
| Update frequency| 12              | 12           |
----------------------------------------------------
```

I would like the new table to display where the values of original and new data does not match. How do I accomplish that? The purpose is to compare original value and new value, to be able to identify changes from original value to new value.

I have been trying to use "Union all" and "Cross join", but any suggestions are very welcome.

Thank you very much for your time.

Answer (score 0):

To find all original tuples which have changed:

```
SELECT [columns you want to compare] FROM Original_data 
--FROM New_data - if you want the new data tuples
EXCEPT
(
SELECT [columns you want to compare] FROM Original_data 
INTERSECT 
SELECT [columns you want to compare] FROM New_data
)
```

You can now join these tables and compare column-wise to get the 'new-data'...

greetings

Comment: Thank you for your answer, though this was not exactly what I was looking for. Your solution will give me muliple columns if I have multiple columns. I only want 3 columns.
`Column 1. <Containing table-column-names>`
`Column 2. <Containing original_data-values>`
`Column 3. <Containing new_data-values>`

The purpose is to be able to _find values from both tables that does not exist in the other_.